# Working with NaN values in channel network in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, clip, valueerror

I have downloaded the conditioned 15s HYDROSHEDS dem of asia and after clipping the desired extent proceeded to evaluate the catchment area. However the next step of channel extraction renders NaN values.

Why does NaN value occur in the conditioned DEM?

Can initiation threshold can lead to such errors?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend referencing [The raster calculator No-data values](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/no_data.html) which goes through

> how to use the raster calculator to perform some operations on raster layers. We will also explain what are no–data values and how the calculator and other algorithms deal with them.

[image]

Another option may be in terms of NaN values occurring in your DEM, from what I'm aware, there is related to the extents of the calculation on the original layer extents of the first raster band on the list. Try to click on the raster band hit the "current layer extent" button.